# How to create a sentence from CSV columns

Tags: php, csv, input

My aim is to create a sentence consisting of three random words which are to be taken from the columns of a CSV file.

I am having troubles with making PHP choose the words only from the correct columns, hence column one contains the words to be first in the sentence, column two only middle words and column three only last words.

**Example of the CSV file:**

```
my;horse;runs
your;chicken;sits
our;dog;barks
```

**Example of the output:**

```
My chicken barks. *reload*
Your horse sits. *reload*
Our dog runs.
```

**My effort so far:**

```
<?php
$file = fopen('input.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
  $x = array_rand($line);
  echo $line[$x] . "\n";
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance and forgive the strong noobness with this one, please.

Comment: Are you trying to code it so that it will be non-repetitive, or can the same value be used from the array more than once? Ie, if `dog` is used in one sentence, can it be used again randomly in another one?

Comment: @Fluffeh The words can be re-used. The objective is to write only single such sentence per page/reload cycle.

Comment: @HarroldCavendish Have any of the answers worked for you?

Comment: @TheoKouzelis Yes, in fact I can not decide which one to accept so I upvoted all of them and accept the most popular one by others' decision later. I am using yours, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would sort the columns into separate arrays then select a random index.

```
<?php
    $file = fopen('input.csv', 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $column1[] = $line[0];
        $column2[] = $line[1];
        $column3[] = $line[2];
    }

    function pickWord($wordArray){
          $x = array_rand($wordArray);
          echo $wordArray[$x] . "\n";
    }

    pickWord($column1);
    pickWord($column2);
    pickWord($column3);
 ?>
```

Something like that

Comment: Thank you very much! I have decided to use this one.

Answer (score 5):

This gives randomized sentences as requested:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('input.csv', 'r');
// prepare token contained
$line = array();
// read csv file line by line
while (!feof($file))
    // fill single line into token container
    $line[] = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";");
// construct a sentence by picking random words from columns
$sentence = sprintf("%s %s %s\n",
                    $line[rand(0,sizeof($line)-1)][0],
                    $line[rand(0,sizeof($line)-1)][1],
                    $line[rand(0,sizeof($line)-1)][2] );
// output sentence
echo $sentence;
?>
```

However it is not very efficient, since it reads the whole csv file into memory first. So it only performs on smaller csv files (say up to a few hundred lines). For bigger files you should consider picking the random line number first and reading only that line from the file. Doing this three times gives you three words you can constrcut your sentence from.

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

```
<?php

$csv = "my;horse;runs
your;chicken;sits
our;dog;barks";

$lines = explode( "\n", $csv );

foreach( $lines as $line ) {
    echo ucfirst( str_replace( ";", " ", trim( $line ) ) ) . "<br />";
}

?>
```

**Output**

```
My horse runs
Your chicken sits
Our dog barks
```